# What does " measures of magnitude larger" mean?

Tags: word-usage

What does " measures of magnitude larger" mean in this context?

> In the same way, CEOs need to constantly be thinking about what’s next. This has always been their role. The key change, however, is that we’re enduring shifts now that they are **measures of magnitude larger** in shorter periods of time.

Comment: It's impossible to say without more context; but I suspect that this is an error for [***orders** of magnitude*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/order-of-magnitude) *larger*. This is a common exaggeration -- it means literally that shifts today compared with those of the past are larger by factors which are not just multiples of single digits (twice, three times, four times) but multiples of powers of ten (ten times, a hundred times, a thousand times).

Comment: I've yet to figure out when a response should be an answer vs. a comment. StoneyB, that seems quite informative enough to be a complete answer.

Comment: I think the question should be closed, but none of the flag options fits it. It seems to originate from an error in the referenced text. No knowledge to be gained.

Answer (score 1):

StoneyB gave us the answer, which I am merely paraphrasing.

> It's impossible to say without more context; but I suspect that this is an error that should be "***orders*** of magnitude." This is a common exaggeration....

Comment: I'd suggest you reread StoneyB's whole answer. "orders of magnitude" is the most likely intended phrase, but it's also most likely an exaggeration. The phrase simply means, I believe, "strikingly larger".

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, I'm curious as to what you're referring to. The four elements I wanted to make sure to include from StoneyB's comment were: a) a definitive answer is impossible without context; b) the actual correct phrase _**orders** of magnitude_; c) "this is a common exaggeration"; and d) stoney's explanation of the literal meaning. What am I missing?

Comment: Since "this is a common exaggeration" , your paraphrase "literally that shifts...are larger by multiple powers of 10" is not appropriate. It just means that the shifts are larger than in the past, and the speaker is exaggerating.

Comment: Okay, @WhatRoughBeast, I can understand where you're coming from. I've whittled out the offending elements. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.